# Ошибка в ассемблере yasm

Tags: ассемблер, yasm

Обучаюсь ассемблеру yasm. Но при компиляции выводит:

> boot.asm:4: error: expected `,' boot.asm:10: warning: value does not fit in 8 bit field

Исходник:

```
use16
org 0x7c00

start:
    mov ah,0xEH
    mov al,"This is working..."
    mov bl,0
    mov bh,0
    int 10h
    jmp $
    
finish:
    times 510+start-finish db 0
    db 0x55,0xAAA
```

Comment: Вы пропустили запятошку **mov al "This is working"**

Comment: уже поставил,теперь воть boot.asm:4: error: expected `,'
boot.asm:10: warning: value does not fit in 8 bit field

Comment: Похоже нельзя передать адрес строки через mov al "String"... Попробуйте задать строку отдельно, типа str db "this is working", 0x0d, 0x0a, '$', а потом уже сделать mov al, str
Вот, можно посмотреть https://montcs.bloomu.edu/Information/LowLevel/Assembly/hello-asm.html

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка у вас, а не "в ассемблере yasm". После исправления опечатки:

```
mov al, "This is working..."
```

Что имеется в виду? Функция `0Eh` выводит символ, а не строку. Вам нужно в цикле, последовательно, помещать в `al` символы строки и выводить их по одному. примерно так (пишу вслепую, сама идея):

```
my_string db "This is working..."
string_length = $ - offset my_string
    ; ...
    cld
    mov si, offset my_string
    mov cx, string_length

next_char:
    lodsb
    mov ah, 0Eh
    ; в bx - нужные атрибуты
    int 10h
    loop next_char
```